# Expected response code 250 but got code "", with message "" When sending emails with Amazon SES and Swiftmailer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses, swiftmailer, symfony-2.1

Sending emails that way used to work fine but the other day, in the mail of a script sending a lot of emails, I started getting this error for every email sent:

> "Expected response code 250 but got code "", with message """

I cannot find any help on the Amazon SES website.

Answer (score 0):

in my case it was because of email processing handled by queue worker, and it looks like transport is open until worker process end, so Swiftmailer send many emails in long-running connection and at some point SMTP server closes connection on timeout.
this code helps if used before `$this->mailer->send()`

```php
if ($this->mailer->getTransport()->isStarted()) {
    $this->mailer->getTransport()->stop();
}
```